# How to render the Error message for longer

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Iam trying to build an application with React for which I have to design a registration form when the user enters the credentials of an existing user i want to display an error message which stays until the user engages with the form.

This is the post request that iam sending to my backend

```
await axios
        .post("http://localhost:5000/user/register", {
          name: user,
          email: email,
          password: pwd,
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          if (res.data) {
            setErrMsg("Username or Email Taken");
          } else {
            setSuccess(true);
          }
        });
```

This is tag that should be displayed

```
                <p
                  ref={errRef}
                  className={errMsg ? styles.errmsg : styles.offscreen}
                  aria-live="assertive"
                >
                  {errMsg}
                </p>
```

I tried using the setTimeout function but to does not work

```
setTimeout(() => {
            setErrMsg("");
          }, 5000);
```

Is there any way to extend the duration for which the error message is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `setTimeout` you can use `eventListeners` on `focus` event to achieve this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("focus", () => {setErrMsg("")}, true); // add eventListener on initial render
    return document.removeEventListener("focus", () => {setErrMsg("")}, true); // remove eventListener on unmount
}, []);
```